# How can I install Doctrine2 Extensions without composer?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I want to install [this](http://gediminasm.org/article/install-gedmo-doctrine2-extensions-in-symfony2).

But I am not comfortable with composer. Is there any other way.

I mean where I can just copy the folder and paste it somewhere

Comment: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Comment: wich version sf 2.0.x or 2.1.x??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after something to put in your deps file you can try

```
[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    version=v2.1.0
[DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
    git=git://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
```